# How can we consider $\infty$ as a real number

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

We know that $\mathbb{R}$ does not contain $\infty$. Tough, it is common that mathematician use $\infty$ as real number for theorems that works just for real number. I do not understand it. Could someone explain to me?

For instance, Let U be an open convex subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and  be a real continuous convex function  on U.   Then  for  each $x\in U$ and $a\in \partial^{e}f(x)$,  there  exists  a  sequence$(x_{n})\subset U$ such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_{n}=x$, f is differentiable at each point $x_{n}$ and $a=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f^{'}(x_{n})$.

How can we show that above theorem works for $x=\infty$?

$$Update$$

I understood first part of my question, but i still do not know how can i show that the theorem works for $x\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "using $\infty$ as a real number. Could you explain?

Comment: @Ruben $\mathbb{R}=(\infty, \infty)$. That is not contained $\infty$. As i said, many theorems that just works for real number like the theorem that i mentioned, it works for $\infty$ too, even though $\infty$ is not real number.

Comment: What do you mean "works for $\infty$ too". It is not defined for that symbol. The result of plugging in $\infty$ may please your eye but that doesn't mean it "works"...

Comment: I knew it. Though, in the above theorem $x=\infty$ does not make sence.

Comment: There's no magical principle that says anything that works for real numbers also works for $\infty$.  Some things do; some things don't.  For the ones that do, you just have to prove the statement for $\infty$ (which typically involves different definitions from the ones used for actual real numbers).

Comment: @Ruben That is my question. How can we show that the theorem works for $x=\infty$?

Comment: @EricWofsey Thank you. Can we show that the above theorem works for $\infty$?

Comment: In the notation of a limit, such as $x\to a$, the value at $x=a$ is never considered. Hence $x\to\infty$ only involves reals. In fact, classical calculus never uses $\infty$ as a real, it doesn't use $\infty$ at all.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thank you. I understood it. I do not know how can i show that the theorem works for $\infty$

Comment: @MR: the theorem does not "work for $\infty$", as $x\in U\subset\mathbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

The notion $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = x$ has a definition and thus $\infty$ is just used for a notion. We did not consider $\infty$ as a number.

One can construct the extended real line though which contains two elements $\pm \infty$. Then you need to figure out how this new notion of $\infty$ behaves and then you can check whether some theorems still work.

One basic thing that does not hold anymore is the following:

The real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ are a field, while the extended real numbers $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ do not even form a semigroup as pretty much all arithmetic operations are not defined for all $x,y \in \overline{\mathbb{R}}$.

The extended real numbers are compact, while $\mathbb{R}$ is not compact.

Something which still works nicely is the exponential function for example. One can continuously extend it.

Comment: Thank you. could you give some examples for me that some of them works and some them not?

Answer (score 2):

The notation
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_{n}=x$$
has a specific conventional meaning; it is *shorthand* for the following:

> For all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $|x_n-x|<\varepsilon$ whenever $n>N$.

It is simply an abbreviation, and I think you will agree that it is a useful one. It is not meant to imply that $\infty$ is a number.

Similarly, the notation
$$[0,\infty)$$
is shorthand for the set

> $$\{x\in\Bbb R\;|\;x\ge 0\}$$

Perhaps less obviously, the notation
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}x_n=\infty$$
is shorthand for

> For all $M>0$ there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that $x_n>M$ whenever $n>N$.

So the notion of $\infty$ as a real number, though suggested by all these notations, is not actually used in their definitions.

There are other examples: $\int_0^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^2}$, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}$ etc. These expressions can all be defined without recourse to the use of $\infty$ as a number; in fact framing these definitions is what a lot of 19th-century mathematics was about.

As ThorWittich remarks, it is possible to give a meaning to $\infty$ as an element of the *extended real number line*. But that belongs to advanced analysis.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser. Does the theorem work for $\infty$?

Comment: @MR: no, the theorem doesn't apply if $x$ is $\infty$, because $\infty\notin U$. As I have tried to show in my answer, $\infty$ is not even _defined_ in most everyday contexts.

Comment: But i saw somwwhere that works for $\infty$

Comment: @MR: then either what you saw was wrong, or your memory of it is flawed.